# Pywinauto can't click on the context menu item

Tags: python, user-interface, automation, ui-automation, pywinauto

Good afternoon, friends! I have a little problem with pywinauto, and i'd like to ask you for little help.

I'm using pywinauto with desktop app, developed in company where i work. The interface of this app is made with QT. This app is used to make videoconferences.

When i'm trying to click on the context menu item from pywinauto, mouse cursor moves on requested element but click doesn't happen. Even background color of this menu item doesn't change (it should change, when hovering the mouse).

Here is a screenshot of how this context menu looks, when accessing by pywinauto (i marked needed menu item):

[accessing menu item with pywinauto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulajX.png)

I tried to access this element by its name and number, also i tried to click this element by it's coordinates from pywinauto (using `mouse` module). I tried to use `set_focus()` method on requested menu item's parent. None of this methods worked.

But if i do this with my mouse by myself, everything is fine, i. e. this menu is accessible.

Here is my code:

`app_dlg['Button4'].click_input() # activating button, which opens context menu app_dlg['MenuItem2'].click_input() # clicking the menu item`

Here is what `print_control_identifiers()` method prints:

```
    Dialog - 'TrueConf — Conference (00:00:07) '    (L1, T1, R1919, B1079)
    ['Dialog', 'TrueConf — Conference (00:00:07) Dialog', 'TrueConf — Conference (00:00:07) ', 'Dialog0', 'Dialog1']
    child_window(title="TrueConf — Conference (00:00:07) ", control_type="Window")
       | 
       | Dialog - 'TrueConf'    (L1350, T36, R1828, B376)
       | ['Dialog2', 'TrueConfDialog', 'TrueConf']
       | child_window(title="TrueConf", control_type="Window")
       |    | 
       |    | Menu - ''    (L1350, T36, R1828, B376)
       |    | ['Menu', 'Menu0', 'Menu1']
       |    |    | 
       |    |    | MenuItem - 'Gallery view'    (L1350, T36, R1828, B81)
       |    |    | ['MenuItem', 'Gallery viewMenuItem', 'Gallery view', 'MenuItem0', 'MenuItem1']
       |    |    | child_window(title="Gallery view", control_type="MenuItem")
       |    |    | 
       |    |    | MenuItem - 'Spotlighted video'    (L1350, T81, R1828, B126)
       |    |    | ['Spotlighted videoMenuItem', 'Spotlighted video', 'MenuItem2']
       |    |    | child_window(title="Spotlighted video", control_type="MenuItem")
       |    |    |
       |    |    | GroupBox - ''    (L1350, T126, R1828, B137)
       |    |    | ['GroupBox', 'GroupBox0', 'GroupBox1']
       |    |    | 
       |    |    | MenuItem - 'Active speaker layout'    (L1350, T137, R1828, B182)
       |    |    | ['Active speaker layout', 'MenuItem3', 'Active speaker layoutMenuItem']
       |    |    | child_window(title="Active speaker layout", control_type="MenuItem")
       |    |    | 
       |    |    | MenuItem - 'Automatically spotlight content window'    (L1350, T182, R1828, B227)
       |    |    | ['Automatically spotlight content windowMenuItem', 'MenuItem4', 'Automatically spotlight content window']
       |    |    | child_window(title="Automatically spotlight content window", control_type="MenuItem")
       |    |    | 
       |    |    | MenuItem - 'Do not display non-video participants in the layout'    (L1350, T227, R1828, B272)
       |    |    | ['Do not display non-video participants in the layout', 'MenuItem5', 'Do not display non-video participants in the layoutMenuItem']
       |    |    | child_window(title="Do not display non-video participants in the layout", control_type="MenuItem")
       |    |    | 
       |    |    | GroupBox - ''    (L1350, T272, R1828, B283)
       |    |    | ['GroupBox2']
       |    |    |
       |    |    | MenuItem - 'Spotlighted window position'    (L1350, T284, R1828, B329)
       |    |    | ['MenuItem6', 'Spotlighted window positionMenuItem', 'Spotlighted window position']
       |    |    | child_window(title="Spotlighted window position", control_type="MenuItem")
       |    |    | 
       |    |    | MenuItem - 'Pin conference controls'    (L1350, T329, R1828, B374)
       |    |    | ['MenuItem7', 'Pin conference controlsMenuItem', 'Pin conference controls']
       |    |    | child_window(title="Pin conference controls", control_type="MenuItem")
       | 
       | Button - 'Menu'    (L14, T14, R59, B59)
       | ['Button', 'Menu2', 'MenuButton', 'Button0', 'Button1']
       | child_window(title="Menu", control_type="Button")
       | 
       | Button - 'Info'    (L312, T15, R329, B32)
       | ['Button2', 'InfoButton', 'Info']
       | child_window(title="Info", control_type="Button")
       | 
       | Button - 'Outgoing format'    (L144, T41, R164, B61)
       | ['Button3', 'Outgoing format', 'Outgoing formatButton']
       | child_window(title="Outgoing format", control_type="Button")
       |
       | CheckBox - 'Notifications'    (L1634, T14, R1679, B59)
       | ['CheckBox', 'Notifications', 'NotificationsCheckBox', 'CheckBox0', 'CheckBox1']
       | child_window(title="Notifications", control_type="CheckBox")
       | 
       | CheckBox - 'Chat'    (L1692, T14, R1737, B59)
       | ['ChatCheckBox', 'CheckBox2', 'Chat']
       | child_window(title="Chat", control_type="CheckBox")
       | 
       | CheckBox - 'Participants'    (L1749, T14, R1794, B59)
       | ['CheckBox3', 'Participants', 'ParticipantsCheckBox']
       | child_window(title="Participants", control_type="CheckBox")
       | 
       | Button - 'Settings layout'    (L1806, T14, R1851, B59)
       | ['Settings layout', 'Button4', 'Settings layoutButton']
       | child_window(title="Settings layout", control_type="Button")
       |
       | CheckBox - 'Fullscreen'    (L1864, T14, R1909, B59)
       | ['Fullscreen', 'CheckBox4', 'FullscreenCheckBox']
       | child_window(title="Fullscreen", control_type="CheckBox")
       | 
       | CheckBox - 'Video'    (L801, T1024, R846, B1069)
       | ['CheckBox5', 'Video', 'VideoCheckBox']
       | child_window(title="Video", control_type="CheckBox")
       |    |
       |    | Button - ''    (L831, T1024, R846, B1069)
       |    | ['Button5']
       | 
       | CheckBox - 'Microphone'    (L856, T1024, R901, B1069)
       | ['Microphone', 'CheckBox6', 'MicrophoneCheckBox']
       | child_window(title="Microphone", control_type="CheckBox")
       |    | 
       |    | Button - ''    (L886, T1024, R901, B1069)
       |    | ['Button6']
       | 
       | CheckBox - 'Sound'    (L911, T1024, R956, B1069)
       | ['Sound', 'CheckBox7', 'SoundCheckBox']
       | child_window(title="Sound", control_type="CheckBox")
       |    | 
       |    | Button - ''    (L941, T1024, R956, B1069)
       |    | ['Button7']
       | 
       | Button - 'Ds'    (L966, T1024, R1011, B1069)
       | ['Button8', 'Ds', 'DsButton']
       | child_window(title="Ds", control_type="Button")
       | 
       | Button - 'More'    (L1021, T1024, R1066, B1069)
       | ['More', 'Button9', 'MoreButton']
       | child_window(title="More", control_type="Button")
       | 
       | Button - 'End call'    (L1076, T1024, R1121, B1069)
       | ['End callButton', 'Button10', 'End call']
       | child_window(title="End call", control_type="Button")
```

Here is a screenshot of how this context menu looks, when accessing by myself with mouse (i marked needed menu item):

[context menu screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaISH.png)

Please, maybe someone can help me... Thank you very much for your time friends!